# How do I combine/ensemble results of 3 machine learning models stored in 3 dataframes and output 1 dataframe with results agreed by majority?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I am currently participating in an online hackathon. All the top entries are within 1% of each other. So I decided to run 3 different models instead of a single best performing one, i.e. ensemble learning, tuned hyperparameters on each one of them and then combine results of all three to get a better model. I've combined results of all three in a dataframe, it's df.head() is as below:

```
index | building_id | rf_damage_grade | xg_damage_grade | lr_damage_grade   | damage_grade

0   a3380c4f75  Grade 4 Grade 2 Grade 3 Grade 4

1   a338a4e653  Grade 5 Grade 5 Grade 5 Grade 5

2   a338a4e6b7  Grade 5 Grade 5 Grade 5 Grade 5

3   a33a6eaa3a  Grade 3 Grade 2 Grade 4 Grade 3

4   a33b073ff6  Grade 5 Grade 5 Grade 5 Grade 5
```

So 'rf_damage_grade' is the column of my best classifier. It gives around 74% accuracy, other two give 68% and 58% respectively. In final output i want, if  'xg_damage_grade' and 'lr_damage_grade' both agree on one value the final output 'damage_grade' gets changed to that value, otherwise it remains equal to the output of 'rf_damage_grade'. There are more than 400k rows in the data and and every time I rerun my model it is taking around an hour to do this on my Early 2015 MBP. Following is the code i've written:

```
for i in range(len(final)):
    if final.iloc[i,2]==final.iloc[i,3]:
        final.iloc[i,4]=final.iloc[i,2]
        if final.iloc[i,3]!=final.iloc[i,1]:
            count+=1
    else:
        continue
```

What can I do to make it more efficient? Is there any inbuilt function in sklearn to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run conditional logic with `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['xg_damage_grade'] == df['lr_damage_grade'], 'damage_grade'] = df['xg_damage_grade']
df.loc[df['xg_damage_grade'] != df['lr_damage_grade'], 'damage_grade'] = df['rf_damage_grade']
```

Or with numpy's `where`:

```
df['damage_grade'] = np.where(df['xg_damage_grade'] == df['lr_damage_grade'],
                              df['xg_damage_grade']
                              df['rf_damage_grade'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It did the work in seconds which took around 2 hours with a 'for' loop. np.where took 0.06133294105529785 seconds and df.loc took 0.15092992782592773 seconds which is a huge improvement from 9000 seconds it was taking earlier.

Comment: @alok.m please, consider to upvote and accept the answer, if it solved your problem

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi thanks for the tip, I've upvoted the answer, but as I'm a new user with less rep, my upvotes don't reflect in count at the moment.

Comment: @alok.m, Glad to help! Often, newcomers to pandas think in the general pythonic way of processing iterable data such as looping through elements. However, in data analytics (Pandas, R, SAS, etc.) you want to work in blocks, processing whole objects in one method. Here, these logic calls are run by pandas series (i.e., columns) not each element of the series. A different way of thinking but useful.